# Logical Volumes fails to mount with dmsetup and no table present

Tags: lvm

I am stuck with all the volumes on a volume group unable to mount, after a yum update on a CentOS 5.11.

device-mapper upgraded from 1.02.24-1 to 1.02.67-2

The machine boots correctly from 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 mounted as /
but refuse to mount all the volumes in /dev/mapper/vg_data

The error in /var/log/messages is 
[...]

```
kernel: device-mapper: multipath: version 1.0.6 loaded
kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:2: mirror: Device lookup failure
kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: device doesn't appear to be in the dev hash table.
kernel: device-mapper: table: device /dev/mapper/lsi_ccfafeaadcb too small for target
kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:6: linear: dm-linear: Device lookup failed
kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:6: linear: dm-linear: Device lookup failed
kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
```

[...]

At boot time the lv nodes are not present, but can be created with

```
vgscan --mknodes
```

Trying to activate the volme group fails with:

```
[root@www ~]# vgchange -ay vg_data
  Found duplicate PV WquAN3yEQuOqUhNhTbrawTqp3YoFxp32: using /dev/hdc2 not /dev/hda2
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
```

But what sounds me strange is that

```
[root@www ~]# pvs
  Found duplicate PV WquAN3yEQuOqUhNhTbrawTqp3YoFxp32: using /dev/hdc2 not /dev/hda2
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/hdc2  VolGroup00 lvm2 a--  74.41G     0
  /dev/hdd4  vg_data    lvm2 a--  60.95G 19.95G
[root@www ~]# vgs
  Found duplicate PV WquAN3yEQuOqUhNhTbrawTqp3YoFxp32: using /dev/hdc2 not /dev/hda2
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  VolGroup00   1   2   0 wz--n- 74.41G     0
  vg_data      1  11   0 wz--n- 60.95G 19.95G
[root@www ~]# lvs
  Found duplicate PV WquAN3yEQuOqUhNhTbrawTqp3YoFxp32: using /dev/hdc2 not /dev/hda2
  LV            VG         Attr   LSize  Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  LogVol00      VolGroup00 -wi-ao 72.47G
  LogVol01      VolGroup00 -wi-ao  1.94G
  lv_ftp        vg_data    -wi-d-  3.00G
  lv_ftpAIRONE  vg_data    -wi-d-  5.00G
  lv_ftpAZI     vg_data    -wi-d-  5.00G
  lv_ftpBAX     vg_data    -wi-d-  3.00G
  lv_ftpBER     vg_data    -wi-d-  3.00G
  lv_ftpBERPCMC vg_data    -wi-d-  3.00G
  lv_ftpBERTEX  vg_data    -wi-d-  3.00G
  lv_ftpPAST    vg_data    -wi-d-  3.00G
  lv_ftpROC     vg_data    -wi-d-  3.00G
  lv_ftpTEA     vg_data    -wi-d-  5.00G
  lv_ftpWURTH   vg_data    -wi-d-  5.00G

    [root@www ~]# lvscan
      Found duplicate PV WquAN3yEQuOqUhNhTbrawTqp3YoFxp32: using /dev/hdc2 not /dev/hda2
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftp' [3.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftpTEA' [5.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftpBAX' [3.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftpROC' [3.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftpBER' [3.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftpAZI' [5.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftpBERPCMC' [3.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftpBERTEX' [3.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftpWURTH' [5.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftpAIRONE' [5.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_data/lv_ftpPAST' [3.00 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00' [72.47 GB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01' [1.94 GB] inherit
```

and this

```
[root@www ~]# dmsetup table
lsi_ccfafeaadcb: 0 240121727 linear 22:64 0
vg_data-lv_ftpBERPCMC:
vg_data-lv_ftpROC:
vg_data-lv_ftpAZI:
vg_data-lv_ftpBAX:
vg_data-lv_ftpBER:
vg_data-lv_ftpPAST:
vg_data-lv_ftpBERTEX:
vg_data-lv_ftpWURTH:
vg_data-lv_ftpTEA:
VolGroup00-LogVol01: 0 4063232 linear 22:2 151978368
lsi_ccfafeaadcbp3: 0 108004176 linear 253:2 4300128
VolGroup00-LogVol00: 0 151977984 linear 22:2 384
lsi_ccfafeaadcbp2: 0 4095504 linear 253:2 204624
lsi_ccfafeaadcbp1: 0 204561 linear 253:2 63
vg_data-lv_ftpAIRONE:
vg_data-lv_ftp:

[root@www ~]# dmsetup info vg_data-lv_ftp
Name:              vg_data-lv_ftp
State:             ACTIVE
Read Ahead:        256
Tables present:    None
Open count:        0
Event number:      0
Major, minor:      253, 6
Number of targets: 0
UUID: LVM-Sca5tWOe0K5PirphI5mojzGxfMoA3HuJZimNY8LgZcH0afeMWrOoTE3AI1jyunJn
```

so all the vg_data volumes has no table in dmsetup.
I think that all datas are there, just need to rebuild the tables, but really don't know how. I already try vgcfgrestore without success.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Can all this mess hav been caused by a yum update?

Thank you

Zaskar

Comment: Ugh. That's messy.

Answer (score 1):

Does anyone have any idea about this as yet ? Why are there blank entries in the device mapper table ?

```
[root@www ~]# dmsetup table
lsi_ccfafeaadcb: 0 240121727 linear 22:64 0
vg_data-lv_ftpBERPCMC:
vg_data-lv_ftpROC:
vg_data-lv_ftpAZI:
vg_data-lv_ftpBAX:
vg_data-lv_ftpBER:
vg_data-lv_ftpPAST:
vg_data-lv_ftpBERTEX:
vg_data-lv_ftpWURTH:
vg_data-lv_ftpTEA:
```